# What is this Java statement containing regex supposed to do?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on some legacy Java code and I see this statement:

```
Pattern lineWithCommentP2 = Pattern.compile("//(.[^<>]+?)(\\R|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = lineWithCommentP2.matcher(s);
s = m.replaceAll("<span class=\"cip\">//$1</span>$2");
```

As per the comment in the code, it is supposed to replace any line of text in the format

```
text1//text2
text3//text4
```

with

```
text1<span class="cip">//text2</span>
text3<span class="cip">//text4</span>
```

However, while testing it, I see that it is replacing the original line with

```
text1<span class="cip">//text2
</span>
text3<span class="cip">//text4
</span>
```

(It is adding a new line after text2 and text4).

I am not able to tweak the regex to avoid that extra line break. Any idea why and how can I fix it?

thank you.

ADDED THE FOLLOWING :
To reproduce, create a text file with this data:

```
<p>test statement </p>
<pre class="code">public class TestClass{   
   public static void main(String[] args){
       statement1; //1
       stement2(); //2
   }
}
</pre>
<p>test stmt</p>
```

Then run the following code :

```
  byte[] ba = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("c:\\temp\\test.txt"));
  String s = new String(ba);
  Pattern lineWithCommentP2 = Pattern.compile("//(.[^<>]+?)(\\R|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = lineWithCommentP2.matcher(s);
  s = m.replaceAll("<span class=\"cip\">//$1</span>$2");
  Files.write(Paths.get("c:\\temp\\test2.txt"), s.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

This generates the following content in test2.text:

```
<p>test statement </p>
<pre class="code">public class TestClass{   
   public static void main(String[] args){
       statement1; <span class="cip">//1
</span>
       stement2(); <span class="cip">//2
</span>
   }
}
</pre>
<p>test stmt</p>
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `$2` in the `replaceAll` call?

Comment: One of the best places to understand a particular regex is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SLwU7c/1)

Comment: Removing $2 removes the new line after </span>. I want to remove the newline that it added on its own before </span>.

Comment: @Priyshrm what is the line separator inserted before `</span>`? `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`?

Comment: @VladimirShefer Ah, my bad. I couldn't reproduce this issue either. You could try adding a `\n` inside the square brackets of `Pattern.compile` (for example `"//(.[^<>\n]+?)(\\R|$)"`)

Comment: Can't repro either, but as a final check, try to exclude any Unicode line breaks, `Pattern lineWithCommentP2 = Pattern.compile("//([^<>\n\\u000B\f\r\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]+)(\\R|$)");`

Comment: Adding \n didn't work. I have added exact code to reproduce this issue in the original post. thanks a lot for your time. Sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is as follows:

```
//            Match '//'
(             Start capture group 1
  .             Match any character, except linebreaks
  [^<>]+?       Match any character, except `<` and `>`, one or more times, reluctantly
)             End capture group 1
(             Start capture group 2
  \\R           Match linebreak, e.g. `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`
  |             OR
  $             Match end of input
)             End capture group 2
```

You have the following text:

```
...\r\n
       statement1; //1\r\n
       stement2(); //2\r\n
...
```

Since capture group 1 is one character plus one or more characters, it means **capture group 1 matches *2 or more* characters**. Since it is *reluctant*, it will stop matching as soon as the remaining pattern is satisfied.

That happens immediately, so you get:

- Group 0: `"//1\r\n"`
- Group 1: `"1\r"`, with `.` matching `"1"` and `[^<>]+?` matching `"\r"`
- Group 2: `"\n"`, with `\\R` matching `"\n"`

**Solution**

To fix, remove the `.` and also make sure group 1 doesn't match linebreak characters, by adding `\v` (vertical whitespace) to the list of excluded characters:

```
"//([^<>\\v]+?)(\\R|$)"
```

*FYI:* Since there are no letters in the regex, specifying flag `CASE_INSENSITIVE` is useless, and misleading, so get rid of it.